# wp_schedule_single_event registers a cron but won't fire the function

Tags: wordpress, cron

I am practicing the schedule events of WordPress. I am writing a function that will show me an alert right after 15s of the time the event was scheduled. I ended up with the following code.

```
        function do_this_in_time() {                    
                echo "<script>alert('');</script>";
        }
        add_action('my_hook_in_time','do_this_in_time');

        wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 15, 'my_hook_in_time');
```

**I know this will schedule events every time I load a page from my site and I also need to put at-least a 10min gap between scheduling events with the same name, I read the doc ;-).**

So Let's say I just loaded the page only one time. But I am still not getting the alert.

I also have checked the scheduled events using **_get_cron_array()** and I can see my event scheduled as follow.

```
[1449843473] => Array
    (
        [my_hook_in_time] => Array
            (
                [40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a] => Array
                    (
                        [schedule] => 
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

But it seems it is not firing off. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to echo Javascript before the page is loaded. The `wp_schedule_single_event` function will fire before the template is displayed, so you will have your `<script>` tag echo'ed before your doctype. Besides that, if someone else visit your website at the moment the event is scheduled he'll get the alert (if it would be echo'ed at the right place), not you.

If you just want to test your cron executions I suggest to log executions in some file on your server instead.

> I know this will schedule events every time I load a page from my site
>   and I also need to put at-least a 10min gap between scheduling events
>   with the same name, I read the doc ;-).

That's not quite right, you'll stack events in your crontab every time page is load, **but** they will be executed **from** 15 seconds of the schedule time. That means one user could have multiple events firing on the same load.

As example:

```
00:00:01 : User visit > Schedule event 1
00:00:02 : User visit > Schedule event 2
00:00:03 : User visit > Schedule event 3
[... no one visit your website in a minute ...]
00:01:00 : Execute events 1, 2 and 3, and schedule event 4
```

Comment: Wowwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww. Great explanation man. I removed the js function and inserted PHP's mail function. Guess what happened? I received the mail :-)

Comment: Don't worry about how I am scheduling the events right now. I was just testing and that seemed to be the quickest way. In actual, I'd attach it with 'publish_post' so there won't be any problem. Really grateful for your explanation :-)